# Multiple Select Dao Mysql Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, dao, multiple-select

I want to build in a select with the possibility of marking more elements. So `multiple="true"`. I use mysql and the Dao Technology of spring. I get the values for the select from database successfully. But now I have a problem when inserting the selected values to my database.

The important tables for that are:

[image: desc]

The table `demo.instrumente` is filled with data like `guitar`, `piano`, etc. and an `id`. These values (i.e. `guitar`, `piano`) are displayed in the multiple select.

A user is able to select maybe 2 or 3 instruments. So I need to add the following instruments to the students. I do this with the table `schueler_instrumente`. Every `student` and `instrument` has an `id`. So i need to create data like this:

```
student_id 1 and instrument_id 2
student_id 1 and instrument_id 5
```

Here is my code for the instrument model class:

```
public class Instrumente {

  private Integer instrumentid;
  private String instrumentname;

  //...getters and setters
}
```

This code is part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(ModelMap model) {
  model.put("instrumentListe", schuelerManager.getinstrumente());
  return "usercenter";
}
```

And here's the relevant part of my schuelerManager

```
public Map<String, String> getinstrumente() {
  Map<String,String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
  for (Instrumente instrument : instrumentDao.getInstrumente()) {
    result.put(instrument.getInstrumentid().toString(),
               instrument.getInstrumentname());
  }
  return result;
}
```

And here's how I get the data from my database:

```
public  List<Instrumente> getInstrumente() {

  return getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM instrumente",
                                 new RowMapper<Instrumente>() {
                                   public Instrumente mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                                                             int rowNum)
                                     throws SQLException {
                                     Instrumente instrument = new Instrumente();
                                     instrument.setInstrumentid
                                       (rs.getInt("Instrument_ID"));
                                     instrument.setInstrumentname
                                       (rs.getString("Instrumentenbezeichnung"));
                                     return instrument;
                                   }
                                 });
}
```

I do now know what I need to do in order to get the selected values from the select list. What do I have to write to the `path="?"` in the jsp.

I think that I can get a list of values back but how can I insert this list to my table `schueler_instrument`. Did I need to make a while or for repeat and make an insert everytime?
I can't find any nice example on the Internet. I hope someone can show me how to do this maybe with some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller's `showUserForm()` you are adding correctly your date to the `ModelMap` (or you could use its Java-5 counterpart [Model](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html)). Now you'll need to use Spring's form tags in your view to represent the options in a dropdown/list way and receive *onSubmit* back in your controller the results that you will further persist in your db.

Have a look for a full example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/).

Something that is not showcased in this example and I suggest you take a look is the `@ModelAttribute` annotation which is a nice way to communicate objects and values between your controller and your jsp view. For an example have a look in [this](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-using-modelattribute-in.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for that tutorial. But I think that example is for an older version of spring not for spring 3 right? Did someone have an example for that with spring 3?

Comment: You have nothing to worry that you are missing in Spring 3 for your scenario. This is perfectly valid in the latest Spring 3.1 release. The only thing is not showcased there that you might want to experiment with is the @ModelAttribute annotation (introduces in 2.5) which is a nice way to communicate objects and values between your jsp and your controller, have a look in this tutorial: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-using-modelattribute-in.html